# Function Returning Set Of Columns

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to return schemas of all the tables present in my schema/database but it's throwing an error-

My Code-

```
create or replace function Table_Schema(schemaname text, tablename text) 
 RETURNS SETOF varchar
 as
$body$
declare
  _query varchar;
begin
 _query := 'select * from information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '''||tablename||''' ';
  RAISE NOTICE '"%"' , _query;

   -- execute and return all
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE _query;
end;
$body$
language plpgsql;


copy(select  
  Table_Schema(table_schema, table_name)
from information_schema.tables
where 
  table_schema  in ('public')) to 'C:\test\Table_Schema.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Could you please help me ? I guess return type is the issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to for dynamic SQL or PL/pgSQL.

```sql
create or replace function Table_Schema(schemaname text, tablename text) 
 RETURNS SETOF information_schema.columns
 as
$body$
 select * 
 from information_schema.columns 
 WHERE table_name = tablename
   and table_schema = schemaname;
$body$
language sql;
```

But to export all columns into a CSV file, you don't really need a function at all:

```
\copy (select * from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'public' order by schema_name, table_name, ordinal_position) to '/path/to/output.csv' with (format csv)
```

Comment: Thanks, Got it. Just a small typo. There should be table_schema instead of schema_name. Can you please edit it so I can accept it as my answer?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to return `setof information_schema.columns`.

```
create or replace function Table_Schema(schemaname text, tablename text) 
 RETURNS setof information_schema.columns
 as
$body$
declare
  _query varchar;
begin
 _query := 'select * from information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '''||tablename||''' ';
  RAISE NOTICE '"%"' , _query;

   -- execute and return all
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE _query;
end;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

But your function does not make much sense because you never use the `schemaname` variable, and the same thing can be achieved by a direct `select` query.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the reply